# Using large lists of custom objects throughout my app

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android app that uses a list of 100 custom objects. This list will not change throughout fragments (it represents characters and their descriptions).

Right now, the list is statically created in an async task in the activity and imported into the fragments, but I do not believe that this is good practice.

What is a better way to use this list of objects?

```
ArrayList declaration in main Activity:

public static ArrayList<Character> characters;
...
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
...
//charactersAPIString is a JSON Array fetched from an API with relevant data
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(charactersAPIString);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        Character newCharacter = new Character(arr.getJSONObject(i));
        characters.add(newCharacter);
    }
}
```

Importing the list into fragment (code appears in each Fragment):

```
import static com.adama.packagename.MainActivity.characters;
```

Comment: "the list is statically created in an async task" -- what do you mean by this? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @CommonsWare The objects in the list are made using JSON objects fetched from an API when the app is initialized

Comment: OK, and what part do you feel is not a good practice?

Comment: @CommonsWare I feel that creating a public static arraylist in the Activity, and importing it into each fragment, is not good practice. But I may be wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "importing it into each fragment"? Bear in mind that we cannot see your code, so we are having to guess as to what you are doing. A [mcve] helps in these cases.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for being unclear. I will edit my question with a few relevant lines of code

Comment: Having a singleton of your model data isn't unreasonable. I would treat this as more of a cache, where you hide the cache and the network access inside of a singleton repository, so the rest of your app is isolated from any of the gory details of getting this data.